# Селекторы jQuery - Выборка элементов по значению атрибута

Tags: jquery

На странице есть родитель:

```
 <span class="flist">
```

Внутри которого циклично выводятся от 3 до 9 div, различаются только цифрой в конце id и ссылок, вот пример первого:

```
<div class="flist-item" id="flist-item-other1">
```

Внутри каждого два span, один с текстом:

```
<span class="flist-label" id="flist-label-other1">ТЕКСТ</span>
```

Второй span

```
<span class="flist-values" id="flist-values-other1">
```

со ссылкой

```
<a href="javascript://" onclick="return categoryFilter('other1',1)">ТЕКСТ ССЫЛКИ</a>
```

Необходимо пройтись по всем `flist-label` и `flist-values`, выбрать текст `$ch_text` и значения ссылок *categoryFilter('other**$ch_name**',**$ch_value**)*, заменить ссылки на чекбоксы:

```
<div class="chdiv"><input type="checkbox" id="ch" name="$ch_name" value="$ch_value">$ch_text</div>
```

Подскажите как правильно сделать выборки? я так понимаю мне надо задействовать:

`$("div[attributeName^='value']")` // Выбирает элемент(ы), которые содержат заданный атрибут, у которого значение начинается с заданной строки.

Хотя нет, я ни фига не понимаю, как пользоваться этими выборками. Научите, пожалуйста!

Comment: как-то поморочено, сделайте fiddle с кодом который вы пробовали

Comment: мне надо получить в переменную текст перед ссылкой и onclick ссылки, onclick в последующем разделить на название other1-9 и значение

Comment: понятнее не стало [вам сюда](http://jsfiddle.net/) [или сюда](http://jsbin.com/)

Comment: good practice: **не пишите штуки типа `onclick="...`, когда используете jQuery**

Comment: реально, сделайте фиддл, если хотите, чтобы вашему вопросу уделили время и обучения начать лучше таки с изучения документации, чтобы понимать, что именно вы делаете, а не заниматься карго-кодингом

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i > 10; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j > 10; j++) {
      var text[i] = $("div#flist-item-other" + i" #flist-label-other" + j).html();
      var onclick[i] = $("div#flist-item-other" + i" #flist-values-other" + j ).attr('onclick');
   }
}
```

Примерно так.
Наверное чушь написал, но было бы лучше, если бы вы пример кода прислали.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать можно так

```
$('.flist .flist-item').each(function(){
var flist-label = $(this).children('flist-label');
var flist-values = $(this).children('flist-values');
//и дальше можете получить айдишники элементов, атрибуты, заменить их на что-то и т.п.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде то что нужно.

Описал действия комментами в коде.

```js
// Как-то так работает ваш цикл?
for(i=1; i<11; i++) {
  $('.flist').append('<div class="flist-item" id="flist-item-other'+i+'">'+
  '<span class="flist-label" id="flist-label-other'+i+'">ТЕКСТ '+i+'</span>'+
  '<span class="flist-values" id="flist-values-other'+i+'">'+
  '<a href="javascript://" onclick="return categoryFilter(\'other'+i+'\','+i+')">ТЕКСТ ССЫЛКИ</a>'+
  '</span>'+
  '</div>');
}
// Если да, то пойдём дальше.
// Т.к. добавление элементов происходит НЕ при загрузки страницы, то искать придётся через .find
// Зачем проходиться по ID, когда классы одинаковые у всех элементов? Пройдёмся по классам.
$('.flist').find('.flist-item').each(function(){
  // Получим текст первого span
  let ch_text = $(this).find('.flist-label').text();
  // Получим значение из onclick
  let onclickAttr = $(this).find('.flist-values a').attr('onclick').match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1].split(',');
  // Получим из значение onclick'а значение "other*"
  let ch_name = onclickAttr[0].replace(/'/g,'');
  // И значение после запятой
  let ch_value = onclickAttr[1];
  // Всё получили, преходим к замене.
  // ----
  // Нужно заменить ссылку на чекбокс? Делаем..
  // Создадим переменную с объектом, в котором будем работать, так, для удобства.
  let changeOBJ = $(this).find('.flist-values');
  // Получим ссылку и удалим её.
  changeOBJ.find('a').remove();
  // Создадим блок с интупом, как вам нужно
  // Ну и прикрутим ему переменные.
  changeOBJ.append('<div class="chdiv">'+
  '<input type="checkbox" id="ch" name="'+ch_name+'" value="'+ch_value+'">'+ch_text+
  '</div>');
});

// Ниже тот же код, только без комментов.
/*
$('.flist').find('.flist-item').each(function(){
  let ch_text = $(this).find('.flist-label').text(),
      onclickAttr = $(this).find('.flist-values a').attr('onclick').match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1].split(','),
      ch_name = onclickAttr[0].replace(/'/g,''),
      ch_value = onclickAttr[1],
      changeOBJ = $(this).find('.flist-values');
  changeOBJ.find('a').remove();
  changeOBJ.append('<div class="chdiv"><input type="checkbox" id="ch" name="'+ch_name+'" value="'+ch_value+'">'+ch_text+'</div>');
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- - -->
<span class="flist"></span>
```

Comment: Лол. Написал код, потом глянул дату вопроса.. Ну да ладно, может кому пригодиться

Comment: сорвался с цепи )))